# How to combine jsbundle and code push if there are two condition?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native

I have set code push in React Native project on XCode.

```
  #ifdef DEBUG
    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  #else
    jsCodeLocation = [CodePush bundleURL];
  #endif
```

Now I want to generate jsbundle and build the project on IOS device.

But I found that `jsCodeLocation` is duplicated.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
    jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
```

I'm confused with it how can I combine the jsCodeLocation ?

I'm not familiar with Objective-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is provided in the example:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "RCTRootView.h"

#import "CodePush.h"

#import "RCTLog.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTSetLogThreshold(RCTLogLevelInfo);

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [CodePush bundleURL];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"CODE_PUSH_TEST_APP_NAME"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/test/template/ios/TestCodePush/AppDelegate.m

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it doesn't include `jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];`

Comment: this is written in plugin information. how to use with NSBundle:
https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/setup-ios.md#plugin-configuration-ios